# ExtJS4 - Disable children views of a form using cascade

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4.2

Good day. I am building a web application. There is a part in my web application where I let a user fill up several forms within a panel. Everything works thus far, however, what I want to do is that when the user views his application, all the fields are disabled so he won't be able to edit them.

My plan is to get the panel and use cascade to get all the children views and disable them. So far what I've tried doing is to reset all the fields in all my forms by doing:

```
console.log("borrower view details selected");

Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').collapse();
Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').expand();
Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').getLayout().setActiveItem(0);

//disable form fields here

Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').items.filterBy(function(c){
   if(c.getXType()==='form'){
       c.getForm().reset();
   }
});
```

From here, I can try two things:

1) Use the cascade and when the `XType` is NOT equal to form, then I disable it.

2) I get the form and do something like `c.getForm().getAllChildren().disable();`

I have tried the first solution but to no avail. I did something like:

```
console.log("borrower view details selected");

Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').collapse();
Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').expand();
Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').getLayout().setActiveItem(0);

//disable form fields here

Ext.getCmp('borrowerRightPanel1').items.filterBy(function(c){
   if(c.getXType()!='form'){
       c.disable();
   }
});
```

However, it does not seem to work. I am pretty new with ExtJS so I'm not too familiar with the functions available for use.

Does any one have an idea on how to execute one or both of my solutions? Which one is much more efficient? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, upon further research, I came across this solution:

```
c.query('.component').forEach(function(c){c.setDisabled(true);});
```

and you can change `.component` to other xtypes such as `.button` or `.field` etc